# C# Regular Expressions, text between slash

Tags: c#, regex

I have 3 type of strings in C#, i want to retrieve text between slash(es) using Regular Expressions

```
string type1 = "www.domain.com/category-name/1.html";

string type2 = "www.domain.com/category-name/sub-category-name/2.html";

string type3 = "www.domain.com/category-name/sub-category-name/sub-sub-category-name/3.html";
```

Q1) From type1 variable i want to retrieve text between first and second slash '/'. i should get **category-name**.

Q2) From type2 variable i want to retrieve text between first and second slash '/', and text between second and third slash '/'. i should get **category-name** and **sub-category-name**

Q3) From type3 variable i want to retrieve text between first and second slash '/', and text between second and third slash '/', and text between third and fourth slash '/'. i should get **category-name** and **sub-category-name** and **sub-sub-category-name**

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a regex? Can't you just split the string on a `/`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this to work, have a look at the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method and the [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) enum.

```
string type1 = "www.domain.com/category-name/1.html";
string[] splicedUrl = type1.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.None);

if (splicedUrl.length > 0)
{
    // Access the correct index, check how many entries the array has etc.
}
```

You might want to have a look at the [following post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Comment: @Faizal And to get all you're expecting just do a for loop from 1 to Length -1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `theString` is the variable you want to parse:

```
var tokens = theString.split('/');
if(tokens.length >= 2)
{
    string category = tokens[1];

    List<string> subCategories = new List<string>();
    for(int k = 2; k < tokens.length - 1; k++)
    {
        subCategories.Add(tokens[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like below using System.Uri:

```
Uri type1 = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/category-name/1.html");
var categoryNameType1 = type1.Segments[1];
Uri type2 = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/category-name/sub-category-name/2.html");
var categoryNameType2 = type2.Segments[1];
var subcategoryNameType2 = type2.Segments[2];
```

This might be slightly more complex than a simple string.Split() but if you need to get more out of a URI like a query, you can easily get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really feel the need to (mis)use a regular expression in this case

```
/([\w-]+)(?=/)
```

should do the trick. This assumes that the items between the slashes are letters and hyphens.

Comment: Nooooo, don't give him a regular expression!

Comment: Kevin's right. This answer is merely code golf. Please don't mark this the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing this. It is equivalent of other answers you already have, but just wanted to post it because it is slightly different:

```
string url = "www.domain.com/category-name/1.html"
var splitted = url.Split('/');
var values = splitted.Skip(1).Take(splitted.Length - 2).ToArray();
```